# sieve to check if from and reply-to are the same

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, sieve

i'm currently trying to set up a sieve rule to check if From and Reply-to headers are the same. If not reject the email. But i can't seem to get it working. I'm thinking of something like that:

```
if header "from" != "reply-to" {
  discard;
}
```

i have found operators and variables can be used, but there is no good documentation on that, at least for me.
could anybody help me please?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

i finally solved it this way:

```
require ["fileinto", "relational", "variables", "editheader"];

if true {
    if allof(header :matches "from" "*", not header :is "reply-to" "${1}")
    {
        if header :matches "Subject" "*"
        {
            deleteheader "Subject";
            addheader :last "Subject" "[PHISHING] ${1}";
        }
    }
}
```